# Get consecutive months and days difference from date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So let's say I have a table like this:

| subscriber_id | package_id | package_start_date | package_end_date | package_price_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1081 | 231 | 2014-01-13 | 2014-12-31 | $3. |
| 1084 | 231 | 2014-03-21 | 2014-06-05 | $3 |
| 1086 | 235 | 2014-06-21 | 2014-09-09 | $4 |

Now I want the result for top 3 packages based on total revenue for each month for year 2014.
Note: For example for package 231 Revenue should be calculated such as 18 days of Jan * $3 +
28 days of feb * $3  + .... and so on.
For the second row the calculation would be same as first row (9 days of March* $3 + 30 days of April *$3 ....)
On the result the package should group by according to month and show rank depending on total revenue.

Sample result:

| Month | Package_id | Revenue | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 231. | 69499 | 1. |
| Jan. | 235. | 34345. | 2. |
| Jan. | 238. | 23455. | 3. |
| Feb. | 231. | 89274 | 1. |

I wrote a query to filter the dates so that I get the active subscriber throughout the year 2014 (since initially there were values from different years),which shows the first table in the question, but I am not sure how do I break the months and days afterwards.

```
select subscriber_id, package_id, package_start_date, package_end_date
from  (
    select subscriber_id, package_id
        , case when year(package_start_date) < '2014' then package_start_date = '01-Jan-2014' else package_start_date end as package_start_date
        , case when year(package_start_date) > '2014' then package_end_date = '31-Dec-2014' else package_start_date end as package_end_date
        , price_per_day 
    from subscription
)  a
where year(package_start_date) = '2014' and year(package_end_date) = '2014'
```

Please do not emphasize on syntax - I am just trying to understand the logical approach in SQL.

Comment: What datatype is the date? (dates are a sticking point across all the SQL implementations)

Comment: Could you please make a sql fiddle and share it.

Comment: The data type is date (YYYY-MM-DD) .

Comment: Actually the first place to start is the syntax... because when you post something like that, which isn't valid, it seems like you've just picked up some random query somewhere. `case` expressions don't work like that.

Comment: @DaleK SQL server would be helpful .

Comment: @DaleK I can post you the question,I am practicing for interview question where I don't have to concentrate on syntax -rather on how to I get the result . The question is available here https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Amazon-Data-Engineer-Interview-Questions-EI_IE6036.0,6_KO7,20.htm?filter.jobTitleFTS=Data+Engineer

Comment: As a devout member of the church of ISO8601, I must humbly request dates in the correct format ( `'2021-02-14'` ). Because the locale of the server will never change on you (it totally will), or as an alternative the more explicit `CONVERT( '2021-02-14' as date)`. I'm sure many people replying to you will also have SQL-Date related PTSD, much like I do.

Comment: The logical way to approach this problem is with a calendar table that gives you the months, you then join your table on and by comparing the valid dates work out which month and how many days a given product is valid for. Then sum it up. Thats quite a bit of work though, so good luck getting someone here to do it.

Comment: I understood the first part but I am not sure how to do " comparing the valid dates work out which month and how many days a given product is valid for" -> for example how do I get the remaining days for the month to calculate revenue? - @DaleK

Comment: As part of your calendar table you will have the start and end dates for each month which you then compare to the start and end dates of your package.

Comment: @burito if you can write a pseudo code for me that works as well. I can make the calendar table with recursive temporary table , but I am not sure how do I compare the values of start date,end-date or join table. I am super confused . Please help me.

Comment: @burito this is going to blow your mind, then: `set dateformat mdy; select convert(datetime, '2021-02-12'); set dateformat dmy; select convert(datetime, '2021-02-12');` Dropping the hyphens yields the expected results in both cases, though: `set dateformat mdy; select convert(datetime, '20210212'); set dateformat dmy; select convert(datetime, '20210212');`

Comment: @DaleK if you can write a pseudo code for me that works as well. I can make the calendar table with recursive temporary table ,sources I found had pre set up start and end date . If I call the months from calendar table through my query  then how do I join the table - like I am having issues visualizing the join operation- for example up until the end date how do I show all the months and days of that particular months. Please help me.

Comment: If you put in your sample data as DDL+DML (i.e. temp table creation and insertion), your calendar table, and an attempt (even if not working), then I am sure many people will help .

Comment: @AlwaysLearning nothing surprises me anymore... but that does draw a single tear from my eye.

Comment: @DaleK give me 15 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a table that is a list of unique dates in a column called d, and the table is called d

It is then relatively trivial to do

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
  INNER JOIN d on d.d >= t.package_start_date AND d.d < t.package_end_date
```

Assuming you class a start date of jan 1 and an end date of jan 2 as 1 day. If you class as two, use <=

This will cause your package rows to multiply into the number of days, so start and end days of jan 1 and jan 11 would mean that row repeats 10 times. The d.d date is different on every row and you can extract the month from d.d and then group on it to give you totals for each month per package

Suppose you've CTEd that query above as x, it's like

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, x.dd), --the d.d date
    package_id,
    SUM(revenue)
FROM x
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, x.dd), package_id
```

Because the rows from T are repeated by Cartesian explosion when joined to d, you can safely group them or aggregate them to get them back to single values per month per package. If you have packages that stay with you more than a year you should also group on datepart year, to avoid mixing up the months from packages that stay from eg jan 2020 to feb 2021(they stay for two jans and two febs)

Then all you need to do is add the ranking of the revenue in, which looks like it would go in at the first step with something like

```
RANK(DATEDIFF(DAY, start, end)*revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY package_id)
```

I think I understand it correctly that you rank packages on total revenue over the entire period rather than per month.. look up the difference between rank and dense rank too as you may want dense instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helping me getting the query right and understand it. Thanks again for helping!